# Rails named_scope syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of sports teams that I am displaying in tables/standings. The relevant code involves two models, Tableposition and Draw, which are associated in a has_one relationship. The following static named scope declaration works perfectly:

```
class Tableposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :draw
  named_scope :grouptable, :include => :draw, :conditions => ['draws.group = ?', "B"]
end
```

However, when I try to make it dynamic:

```
class Tableposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :draw
  named_scope :grouptable, :include => :draw, 
                lambda { |group| { :conditions => ['draws.group = ?', group] } }
end
```

I get the following error:

SyntaxError: /.../app/models/tableposition.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

I've scoured the web for solutions and have tried converting the curly braces to a do ... end with brackets to no avail.  Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

named_scope wants arguments like this: `(name, options)` You were giving it `(name, include option, condition option)` Where both include and condition options were hashes. Instead you need to give it one merged hash.

Corrected code:

```
named_scope :grouptable, lambda { |group|
  {  :include => :draw, :conditions => ['draws.group = ?', group] } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Around here that's shown by voting up and accepting an answer. A green checkmark goes a long way in helping others who have a similar questions.

Comment: Will do.  Don't have enough "rep" to do it yet, but I'll come back when I do.  Thanks again.